# Prevent entity deletion in doctrine 2 listener

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I need to make entities to change status except being deleted. For those I added a listener for on flush method. So, I can see all the entities, that being deleted, but cannot prevent them to be deleted. Is it possible?

Comment: Please rephrase your question and make sure it's understandable. People are unlikely to help you atm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Throwing a Exception in the event handler cut the transaction and rollback the changes.

```
public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $em = $eventArgs->getEntityManager();
    $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

    foreach ($uow->getScheduledCollectionDeletions() AS $col) {
         throw new Exception('avoid delete');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install doctrine extension https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md or use it as an example to develop your own solution